# Connecting over TCP without port forwarding?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, tcp, tcpclient

Okay so I'm using a TCP networking library called Telepathy in combination with the unity engine (both C#) to make a multiplayer game, Telepathy is an incredibly simple library so it's basically just raw TCP.

When connecting to a TCP server remotely the host would need to get into their router settings and port forward to their pc to make sure the client is able to connect.

I was wondering if there would be a way to circumvent this process entirely? As in making sure the host doesn't have to mess with their router settings at all?

Comment: It's called UPnP.  I'm sure your router supports it.

Comment: UPnP as in universal plug and play right? Would you say support across routers is broad? Since I'm working with a (sort of) p2p model virtually any player would be able to host.